# How to Join Pyspark Dataframe that is In Between 2 Columns of another Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes, one of them consist of 1 column of integers and the 2nd dataframe consist of 3 columns (integer_start, integer_end, animal).

*dataframes and their columns*

```
dataframe1 -> integer

dataframe2 -> integer_start, integer_end, animal
```

So what i want to do is to join these 2 dataframes such that 
if

```
dataframe1.integer is in between dataframe2.integer_start and dataframe2.integer_end
```

take out dataframe1.integer and the respective dataframe2.animal and put into a new dataframe called dataframe3

Hope you can help me with this. I am using PySpark for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a simple join to do this.

```
result= dataframe1.join(dataframe2,[ dataframe2.integer_start <= dataframe1.integer  , dataframe2.integer_end >= dataframe1.integer ], how='inner').select("integer","animal")
```

This will give you exactly what you need.

Depending on whether you want to include the edge cases you can remove the = in <= and >=.